# Confusion between new something() and new something[] in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider class A:

```
class A
{
public:
int x;
int y;
}
```

Now if we write `A *a = new A()` then **a** is a pointer to an element of class A. However, if we write `A *a = new A[5]` then **a[0]** is not a pointer but an instance of class.

I was expecting `a[n]` to behave like a pointer and thus operations like `a[0]->x` to hold valid.

What is the flaw in my understanding?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of `A *a[5];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `a` is a pointer, the syntax `a[N]` is, by definition, equivalent to `(*(a + N))`. So the dereference is already included in the expression. The difference between `new A()` and `new A[N]` is in what's allocated (a single element vs. multiple elements). However, in both cases, a pointer to a single element is returned (the only element in the case of `new A()`, and the first element in the case of `new A[N]`). And the syntax which can be used on that pointer is the same in both cases. Note the following:

```
A* a = new A();
a[0].x = 10;
```

This is a legal (albeit uncommon) way to access the single object which was allocated by the expression `new A()`. Likewise:

```
A* a = new A[N];
a->x = 10;
```

That is a legal way to access the first element of the array which was allocated by the expression `new A[N]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards.

```
A *a = new A();
a[0]->a = 5;
```

Will not compile, because the straight bracket operator returns a reference to an array element, not a pointer to the space.  It can be thought of as equivalent to `*(a + 0)`.  This means that `a[0].a` is the way to reference a member of the class instance when using the bracket operator.  Note that you are correct that `a->a = 5` will compile, but that would be equally true if you had declared `a` as `A a[5];`

Answer (score 0):

`A *a[5]`;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
     A *p = new A;
     a[i] = p;
 }
```

is what you want, recommend `std::vector` instead. `A *a = new A[5]` means `a` is a pointer to an array of objects, so `a[i]` is a object.